# Android: Same listView on different Activities

Tags: android

I want to have the same listview (with same fields) in 2 different activities. In one Activity, per each item, I want to show 2 buttons and in the another activity I don't want to show those buttons.

Does anyone knows how can I modify my Adapter code to obtain it?
(To construct my listview I'm using an adapter).

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{
(...)

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_info, null);
        }

        String quantia=String.valueOf(list.get(position).getQuantia());

        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position).getNome());
        TextView listItemText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantia);
        listItemText2.setText(quantia+" €");
        TextView listItemText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoria);
        listItemText3.setText(list.get(position).getCategoria());

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ImgButtonDel);
        ImageButton editBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ImgButtonEdit);


        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
(...)
}
```

Comment: Pass Activity instance or one flag to your adapter and based on that handle (Visible/Invisible) your views in adapters.

Comment: You can use `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` to appear and disapprear your buttons in your `getView`, better use `ViewHolder` pattern